# Adding Blogengine.net posts to my home page

Tags: blogengine.net

I've installed BlogEngine within my website and I want to show the posts on the homepage of my website. How do I do this?

Thanks

Comment: If I've been -1 can you at least do me the courtesy of explaining your reasoning so I don't make a similar mistake?

Comment: This question is vague, might be on the wrong site, and incomplete. "Show the posts on the homepage of my website". Do you mean you want to make blogengine-posts available through your main website, which isn't hosted through blogengine?

Comment: This is a good post. I have up voted you. I would also like to know how to do this.. I have created a question recently - because i am going to carry out this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of the version of BE.NET you're using, but I'd probably recommend using the main RSS feed.

This would allow you to programmatically display your articles either via server- or client-side code.

If you want to tell us more about your environment I can point you towards some resources for one of the above, if needed.

(Off the cuff, if I were implementing I'd use jQuery for the client-side and LINQ to XML server-side.)